# R: Mean subset sequence from dataframe

Tags: r

I have been facing a problem for three days and I cannot get any answer about why it does not work. I have tried quite a lot different ways, but I am just going to post the one I believe is likely to be closest to the solution. I am going to put a reduce example about what I want to ask.

I have **7 csv files** (called 001.csv, 002.csv, ... etc), in a folder called "**Myfolder**".
I have been trying to get a **function** that **merged** into an unique **data.frame** all this different .csv files using **for-loop and r.bind** and finally **return** the **mean** from either column "Colour1" or "Colour2" depending in the "colour" (column) and the "Children" (rows) I choose, and of course without missing values "Na". As an example when I merge the files I get a data frame like this data frame:

```
         Colour1  Colour2   Children    
            NA     NA         1
            9      NA         2
            NA     NA         2
            NA     5          3
            7      NA         4
            NA     NA         5
            NA     8          5
            2      NA         6
            6      3          6
            14     NA         7
```

This is the the example of the function I want to build  **get_mean <- function(directory, colour, children)**

What I have tried

```
    get_mean <- function(directory, colour, children) {
      files <- list.files(directory, full.names=TRUE)
      allfiles <- data.frame()
      for(i in 1:7) {
            allfiles <- rbind(allfiles, read.csv(files[i]))
      }
      if(colour == "colour1"){
            mean(allfiles$colour1[allfiles$Children == children], na.rm = TRUE)
      }
      if(colour == "colour2"){
            mean(alllists$colour2[alllist$Children == children], na.rm = TRUE)
      }      
}
```

When I tried for example:

```
get_mean("Myfolder", "colour1", 3:6)
```

I get

```
In alllist$ID == id :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
```

and when I try:

```
get_mean("Myfolder", "colour1", 6)
```

I get:

```
>
```

Yes guys....I get back absolutely nothing.

What do you think guys? any correction to it? any other way to get the mean?

Note: all the data I put in here is not the one I am using. This is just an example from an exercise much bigger. I have tried to make a really small example with different names and numbers in order to don't discuss about the exercise itself and other could copy the solution

Comment: Is `alllists` a typo? You probably want `allfiles$Children %in% children`. You also need to wrap the intended return values in `return()` otherwise the function will return the last returned value of its content which is `invisible(NULL)` if the second `if` condition is `FALSE`. (I won't comment on better ways to do this right now.)

Comment: Thanks for the tips Roland! I appreciate them!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a corrected and more readable version of your function - I named your `data.frame` all files `df`, I also added a check on `colour`:

```
get_mean <- function(directory, colour, children) {

    files = list.files(directory, full.names=T)

    df = do.call(rbind, lapply(files[1:7], read.csv))

    # check the colour argument
    if(!is.element(colour, c('colour1','colour2'))) 
      stop(sprtinf('colour argument value %s is not part of df column', colour))

    mean(df[[colour]][df$Children == children], na.rm=TRUE)
```

}

Comment: Thank you so much Colonel ! It works perfectly and it is easy to understand it. I really appreciate your time in answering my question. It seems i need to keep improving ... ;D

Comment: No problem, just remenber the less line, often the best! No loop, apply function are more functional oriented ;) But your question is clear and encouraging since you defined exactly what you wanted, it's already a big step!